# array_diff() removes too many elements

Tags: php, arrays

I use the code below to get the difference from two arrays. But as it seems right now it removes too many elements or I'm doing something wrong.

I expect the output to be `array(333, 111)`, because the element `111` appears two times in the first array and only once in the second one. So 1x`111` should be in the output. But as of right now `111` is completely missing in the output.

Am I doing something wrong or what should I do to get this function to work as I want to?

```
<?php

    $Inventory1 = "111,222,333,111";
    $SplitInventory1 = explode(",",$Inventory1);

    $Invoice = "111,222";
    $SplitInvoice = explode(",",$Invoice);


    $SplitResult1 = array_diff($SplitInventory1, $SplitInvoice);    
    echo $JointInventory1 = implode(",",$SplitResult1);

?>
```

Comment: `array_diff()`(Same for the similar functions) do not take the amount of the same elements into account. So if there is now 1x`111` or 10x`111` in the array does not matter it will just have it once in the output, or not. So for what you want you want to write your own function using some simple foreach loop to unset each element from one array in the other.

Comment: *"`array_diff` returns the values in array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays"* – `111` exists in the other array, why should it be returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HI i have used `array_filter` to filter the values of `$SplitInventory1` array using `$SplitInvoice`. If `array_filter's` `callback function` return `true` then present value will be placed into new `array`.

so stpes will be

1) `$var` will carry the values of first array like `111,222,333,444` and using `array_search` it will check these exist or not in `$SplitInvoice`array.

2)`array_search` return the `key` of found value so when 111 and 222 found in `$SplitInvoice` array then callback function will return false and these values will be not place in `$diff` but when 333 is searched in `$SplitInvoice`. this will not found in `$SplitInvoice` and callback function will return true and it will be placed in `$diff`.

3) One more thing I have `unset` `$SplitInvoice` array if a value found beacuse we need dublicate entries( due to 111 if $SplitInvoice is not unset then it will not come in `$diff` )

```
<?php
    $Inventory1 = "111,222,333,111";
    $SplitInventory1 = explode(",",$Inventory1);
    $Invoice = "111,222";
    $SplitInvoice = explode(",",$Invoice);
    $diff = array_filter($SplitInventory1, 
  function ($val) use (&$SplitInvoice) { 
    $key = array_search($val,$SplitInvoice);
    if ( $key === false ) return true;
    unset($SplitInvoice[$key]);
    return false;
  }
);

echo "<pre>";print_r($diff);

?>
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [2] => 333
    [3] => 111
)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: i really need the explanation of this codes it works but i need to know how it works :(

Comment: @ShermaineChaingan Always ask for an explanation of the code. This will improve the long term quality of the answer on one side and on the other side understanding the code will make it easier for you to modify it and learn from it.

Comment: i cant apply the codes when i did not know how its really works

Comment: @ShermaineChaingan please find the explanation and ask answer if you not get anything

Comment: For All others as SO is a learning site as all did everyone google for new knowledge. Patient is the key of success. I am also a new learner if i am answering any question by copying or searching from anywhere its my thought that i will learn something new. i have not forced anyone to upvote this or accept this